# how to assign the button id dynamically in MVC Action

Tags: model-view-controller

i declare the button in .aspx its id is btn1

My prob is ,i need to assign the class name of the button and value of the button in action side(i.e in controller)

Answer (score 1):

Use the ViewData dictionary.

```
public ActionResult Show()
{
    ViewData["ButtonClassName"] = "my-class-name";
    ViewData["ButtonId"] = "my-id";
    View();
}
```

And in the view:

```
<%= Html.SubmitButton("name", "text", new { @class = ViewData["ButtonClassName"], id = ViewData["ButtonId"] }) %>
```